# How to automatically tangle another source block to file when evaluate a source block in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

The source block what I want to evaluate (src2) need to source a file which should be the tangle result of another source block (src1). How could it make the tangle to file automatically everything time I evaluate the source block?

src1: should be tangle to file:

```
+begin_src tcl :tangle /tmp/compile_lib.tcl
  <some tcl code>
+end_src
```

src2: would be evaluated.

```
+begin_src sh
   vivado -mode batch -source /tmp/compile_lib.tcl    # source the file tangled from <src1>
+end_src
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After look around, I work out a workaround to do it by set a dummy variable for the `src2` block to tangle the `src1` block.

Solution:
    1. First, you have to name the `src1` block to make it easy be located.
    2. Create a dummy variable to use elisp to tangle `src1`.

Example Code:

```
#+NAME: my_hello
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle /tmp/hello.el
  (message "Hello")
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var DUMMY=(progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "my_hello") (org-babel-tangle '(4))) :results output
  cat /tmp/hello.el
  rm -f /tmp/hello.el
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (message "Hello")
```

This solution solve my problem for now. But it has a lot of limitations, such as it can only tangle the block in the same org-mode file.

Hope some would work out a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need everything to tangle into a single file, you can use this incredibly hacky workaround that uses orgmode to turn a table into generated code in a second (or third!) language.

Your table (1):

```
#+tblname: personae-table
| Set | Description        | variable | Value |
|-----+--------------------+----------+-------|
| DEP | Fam Med Department | famDep   | 23    |
```

Your code generator (2):

```
#+name: python-generate-new-and-set-vars-blocks
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var records=personae-table :exports results :results output verbatim drawer
  print("#+name: variables")
  print("#+BEGIN_SRC mumps")

  print("n " + ",".join(line[3] for line in records))
  print("s " +
        ",".join(
            "{}={}".format([line[2], str(line[3])]) for line in records))
  print()
  print("#+END_SRC")
#+END_SRC
```

Your generator's results (3):

```
#+results: python-generate-new-and-set-vars-blocks
:RESULTS:
#+name: variables
#+BEGIN_SRC mumps
n famDep
s famDep=23
#+END_SRC
:END:
```

Your dummy block that pre-compiles the blocks to tangle (4):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes :var DUMMY=(progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "python-generate-new-and-set-vars-blocks") (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c))
; run pre-tangle hooks by putting them in the var.
#+END_SRC
```

Your output block that tangles the generated code (5):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC mumps :tangle fixed.m :noweb tangle :padline no
  run()
    <<variables>>
#+END_SRC
```

Execution goes 4, 1, 2, 3, 5.  I'm not sure if I should be proud or ashamed.  Orgmode is amazing.