# quickly clear org babel results buffer

Tags: org-babel

How to quickly remove this bit

```
#+RESULTS:                                                                                                                     
:RESULTS:                                                                                                                      
20                                                                                                                             
21                                                                                                                             
22                                                                                                                             
23                                                                                                                             
24
...
```

when working in org mode?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-x org-babel-remove-result` or <kbd>C-c C-v k</kbd> (`org-babel-remove-result-one-or-many`) removes the result of the current source block.

Comment: hey can I ask a side question, unrelated -  the way I do it (with "heredoc") messes up syntax coloring. Is there a way to achieve what I'm doing without heretic.

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior The syntax coloring of here-document is correct, though It would make more sense to highlight `<<EOF` as well. If you don't like the color, you can customize the `sh-heredoc` face.

Comment: the syntax coloring ignores the ruby code syntax coloring. i don't want to read ruby code without its coloring

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior I think here-document is simply String. Asking Emacs to "guess" that's Ruby code then highlight as Ruby code is not very realistic.

Comment: thats why I'm asking is there another way to do it without resorting to "heredoc"

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior may be writing a ruby code block and tangling it to your .rb file could be a way to keep ruby syntax coloring in you org file. Then you can write another sh code block to execute your ruby file. Doc for tangling : https://orgmode.org/manual/tangle.html

Comment: So I would have to do "C-c C-c" for twice? I kindof don't want to let go of my one keystroke workflow

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior may be you could find a solution in this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14445/9245. The idea is to automatically tangle a specific code block (for instance your ruby block) when evaluating a second code block (for instance your sh block). The key point is to name the ruby code block and then to add the following code    :var DUMMY=(progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "name of the ruby blosk") (org-babel-tangle '(4))) in the header of your sh code block.

You can with this in mind keep a single keystroke workflow and benefit of syntax coloring.